# Reading UML diagrams (POODR)

Tags: ruby, class, oop, uml

I'm reading [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/) and trying to wrap my head around Sandi's examples.

I'm especially interested in trying to understand how her UML diagrams work.

For example Figure 4.8 on page 75:

[image]
Looking at the image some questions come to mind:

1. moe Customer - This represents an instance of the `Customer` class, perhaps with an attribute name equal to `moe`, or perhaps it's an instance stored in a variable named `moe`, either way the diagram makes it look like this box represents "an object that is and instance of the Customer class"?
2. a TripFinder - This is a little confusing because it also seems like it represents "an object that is an instance of the TripFinder class"?
3. class Trip and class Bicycle - Now we see the `class` keyword, so does is Sandi trying to say that those boxes represent "a Trip Class object" or "a Bicycle Class object"? Both of which are "objects that are instances of the Class class"?
4. An arrow seems to go from the "sender" to the "receiver" of a "message". In code that translates to "calling a method on the receiver object"? The fact that the arrow is coming from moe means that somewhere inside the `Customer` class there is a method that calls the `TripFinder#suitable_trips` instance method. So the arrow going from the "sender" to the "receiver" tells us the receiver's method name (aka method signature?) but not the sender's method name right?
5. What do the response arrows mean? Are they only return statements? What is the significance of a dotted vs. a solid line? I know in some diagrams they represent dependencies but now it seems like they are representing sending a message and getting a return statement. Is that the same thing as a dependency?
6. Why is the last line a solid line? Is it just a typo?

Comment: See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-reference.html

Comment: Well, just as a side-note those diagrams are somewhat far from being fully UML compliant. In the lifeline the name and class should be separated with a colon, not a space (so e.g. `moe:Customer`). There should be a combined fragment to represent loop instead of putting a constraint. Arrow ends should either be a filled triangle or open arrowhead (co consist of only two lines). Those heads are neither filled triangles (then response would have incorrect head - it should be open) nor open head (then all messages are synchronous and can't have responses). It doesn't support understanding diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, this has been created with a painting tool, not an UML CASE tool.

1. (up to 3.) This naming is wrong. The lifeline is either described with just the instance `name`, `:classifier` or as `name:classifier`. See p. 570 17.3.4.1 Lifeline in the spec:

> A Lifeline is shown using a symbol that consists of a rectangle forming its “head” followed by a vertical line (which may be dashed) that represents the lifetime of the participant. Information identifying the lifeline is displayed inside the rectangle in the following format:
>
> ```
> <lifelineident> ::= ([<connectable-element-name>[‘[‘ <selector> ‘]’]] [: <connectable-element-type>] [<decomposition>]) | ‘self’`
> <selector> ::= <expression>
> <decomposition> ::= ‘ref’ <interactionident> [‘strict’]
> ```

4. correct
5. The dashed return messages are optional. You can place them for clarity or to show special return values/conditions. Connector notations in UML are most confusing. In all (or most?) other diagrams a dashed line with open arrow means a dependency. See. p. 720 of the specs for correct dash/arrow use (the arrows in the example above are incorrect, since "artistic" with curves).
6. Yes. See 1-3 and the top remark.

Probably, I'd throw that book in the dump...